# Continuous Function From Compact Space to Hausdorff Space is an Identification

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, quotient-spaces

Mendelson's *Introduction to Topology: Third Edition*, Chapter 5, Section 1, Question 6:

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous mapping of a compact space $X$ onto a Hausdorff space $Y$.  Prove that $f$ is an identification.

Comment: It’s **onto** $Y$. Every word matters. So $f$ is assumed to be surjective.

Comment: That makes sense.  I suppose I was treating the word onto as you would to, because in English they are generally interchangeable.  If it were included in the $f:X \rightarrow Y$ notation, then I would not have ignored it, because I tend to assume mathematical notation has a mathematical meaning.  I clearly do not always do this with words in a mathematical context.

Comment: Sometimes $f:X \twoheadrightarrow Y$ is used to denote ontoness. The clue can be in words or symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show that if $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $X$ for some $C \subseteq Y$ then $C$ is closed in $Y$.

1. $f^{-1}[C]$ is compact (as $X$ is compact).
2. $C=f[f^{-1}[C]]$ because $f$ is onto (i.e. surjective).
3. As $f$ is assumed to be continuous, $C$ is compact.
4. As $Y$ is Hausdorff, $C$ is closed in $Y$.

QED.
See how all assumptions are used..

Answer (score 0):

Let both $X$ and $Y$ be the real interval $[0,1]$ and let $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $X$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are both compact and both Hausdorff.  A constant function is continuous, but $f$ is not surjective so it is not an identification.

From this, we realise that *we are supposed to assume that $f$ is surjective*, so then it only remains to show that any subset of $Y$ with open preimage is open. (This part is fine)

But this seems to come up a lot... sometimes the notation $f:X \rightarrow Y$ means that $f$ is mapping into (possibly only a subset of) $Y$, while at other times it seems to be implicitly "understood" that $f$ is surjective.  Frustrating...

Comment: 'Onto' is synonym for 'surjective'.